# Hooking up Reporting Services 2005SP2 to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, system-administration

I am trying to configure Reporting Services 2005SP2 on a machine with SQL 2008 on another hosting the ReportServer DB.

When I create the ReportServerDB the DB is created as version C.0.9.45:

When, afterwards, I try to initialise Reporting Services, I get an error about an incorrect version number. Reporting Services created a ReportServer DB version C.0.9.45 but now expects a version C.0.8.54.

Changing compatibility settings of the DB doesn’t have an effect. And changing the version number sproc in the DB to return what Reporting Services wants to hear only delays the crash until initialisation has started.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a reply from microsoft support saying that it is impossible on the same box.

http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=4153333&SiteID=1

Answer (score 0):

You must have created the reportServerDB using the SQL 2008 configuration tool. If you want to use the 2005 version of the server you need to create the configuration database using the configuration tool that came with SQL 2005. The 2005 SP2 tool will create a database with version C.0.8.54

Comment: No. The ReportServer DB has been created with the SQL 2005 configuration tool. The sproc reporting the version number also seems to change when I move the DB from SQL 2005 to SQL 2008.

Comment: How are you "moving" the DB. I'm pretty sure that moving the DB should not change the stored proc in any way. I have both SSRS 2005 & 2008 running side by side on my laptop and they work fine although I have the repository DBs of each in different DB Server instances so this is not quite the same.